# Best way to continuously switch between 2 different fragments/activities/tabs in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-animation, android-tabs

Basically I want to have 2 different pages or screens and at the top of each one there's is a button. When that button is click it changes to the next page and visa versa. I was just wondering what is the most efficient way to switch between those 2 pages. Should I make 2 different activities and then just use intents to switch between them. Or should I use fragments and use fragmentTransaction().show or .replace() to switch between them or is there a better way. Because I also want a sort of slide animation when it switches between the pages. Just wondering what do you think is the best way to achieve this... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an interface in both the fragments and implement them in activity and communicate via them. Instruct the activity to switch the fragments on the interface implementation  for how to communicate between fragment and activity

Read here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html